# Performance benefits of a static empty array instance

Tags: java, arrays, performance

It seems common practice to extract a constant empty array return value into a static constant. Like here:

```
public class NoopParser implements Parser {
    private static final String[] EMPTY_ARRAY = new String[0];

    @Override public String[] supportedSchemas() {
        return EMPTY_ARRAY;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Presumably this is done for performance reasons, since returning `new String[0]` directly would create a new array object every time the method is called – but would it really?

I've been wondering if there really is a measurable performance benefit in doing this or if it's just outdated folk wisdom. An empty array is immutable. Is the VM not able to roll all empty `String` arrays into one? Can the VM not make `new String[0]` basically free of cost?

Contrast this practice with returning an empty String: we're usually perfectly happy to write `return "";`, not `return EMPTY_STRING;`.

Comment: Isnt the benefit that you are returning the same  array every time, so you dont have to make one each time you return. Like using a template

Comment: The VM can't make such an assumption. For example, maybe you want to create a new empty array that will be used in reference equality.

Comment: saves a bit of typing too :D

Comment: You are right. JVM could to a lot of job for compiler. Edit: Why do we need the compiler after all? It cannot even merge string arr allocations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm most interested in the actual performance difference between these two idioms in practical, real-world situations. I have no experience in micro-benchmarking (and it is probably not the right tool for such a question) but I gave it a try anyway.

This benchmark models a somewhat more typical, "realistic" setting. The returned array is just looked at and then discarded. No references hanging around, no requirement for reference equality.

One interface, two implementations:

```
public interface Parser {
    String[] supportedSchemas();
    void parse(String s);
}
```

```
public class NoopParserStaticArray implements Parser {
    private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];

    @Override public String[] supportedSchemas() {
        return EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY;
    }

    @Override public void parse(String s) {
        s.codePoints().count();
    }
}
```

```
public class NoopParserNewArray implements Parser {
    @Override public String[] supportedSchemas() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override public void parse(String s) {
        s.codePoints().count();
    }
}
```

And the JMH benchmark:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;

public class EmptyArrayBenchmark {
    private static final Parser NOOP_PARSER_STATIC_ARRAY = new NoopParserStaticArray();
    private static final Parser NOOP_PARSER_NEW_ARRAY = new NoopParserNewArray();

    @Benchmark
    public void staticEmptyArray() {
        Parser parser = NOOP_PARSER_STATIC_ARRAY;
        for (String schema : parser.supportedSchemas()) {
            parser.parse(schema);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void newEmptyArray() {
        Parser parser = NOOP_PARSER_NEW_ARRAY;
        for (String schema : parser.supportedSchemas()) {
            parser.parse(schema);
        }
    }
}
```

The result on my machine, Java 1.8.0_51 (HotSpot VM):

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt           Score          Error  Units
EmptyArrayBenchmark.staticEmptyArray  thrpt   60  3024653836.077 ± 37006870.221  ops/s
EmptyArrayBenchmark.newEmptyArray     thrpt   60  3018798922.045 ± 33953991.627  ops/s
EmptyArrayBenchmark.noop              thrpt   60  3046726348.436 ±  5802337.322  ops/s
```

There is no significant difference between the two approaches in this case. In fact, they are indistinguishable from the no-op case: apparently the JIT compiler recognises that the returned array is always empty and optimises the loop away entirely!

Piping `parser.supportedSchemas()` into the black hole instead of looping over it, gives the static array instance approach a ~30% advantage. But they're definitely of the same magnitude:

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt           Score         Error  Units
EmptyArrayBenchmark.staticEmptyArray  thrpt   60   338971639.355 ±  738069.217  ops/s
EmptyArrayBenchmark.newEmptyArray     thrpt   60   266936194.767 ±  411298.714  ops/s
EmptyArrayBenchmark.noop              thrpt   60  3055609298.602 ± 5694730.452  ops/s
```

Perhaps in the end the answer is the usual "it depends". I have a hunch that in many practical scenarios, the ***performance* benefit in factoring out the array creation is not significant.**

I think it is fair to say that

- if the method contract gives you the freedom to return a new empty array instance every time, and
- unless you need to guard against problematic or pathological usage patterns and/or aim for theoretical max performance,

then returning `new String[0]` directly is fine.

Personally, I like the expressiveness and concision of `return new String[0];` and not having to introduce an extra static field.

---

By some strange coincidence, a month after I wrote this a real performance engineer investigated the problem: see [this section](http://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/#_caching_the_array) in Alexey Shipilёv's blog post 'Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients':

> As expected, **the only effect whatsoever can be observed on a very small collection sizes, and this is only a marginal improvement over `new Foo[0]`.** This improvement does not seem to justify caching the array in the grand scheme of things. As a teeny tiny micro-optimization, it might make sense in some tight code, but I wouldn’t care otherwise.

That settles it. I'll take the tick mark and dedicate it to Alexey.

Answer (score 6):

I benchmarked it using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

```
private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];

@Benchmark
public void testStatic(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(jvmArgs = "-XX:-EliminateAllocations")
public void testStaticEliminate(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
}

@Benchmark
public void testNew(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(new String[0]);
}

@Benchmark
@Fork(jvmArgs = "-XX:-EliminateAllocations")
public void testNewEliminate(Blackhole blackhole) {
    blackhole.consume(new String[0]);
}

@Benchmark
public void noop(Blackhole blackhole) {
}
```

[Full source code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/22f95ff41a2ac709a303).

Environment (seen after `java -jar target/benchmarks.jar -f 1`):

```
# JMH 1.11.2 (released 51 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.7.0_75, VM 24.75-b04
# VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
```

`EliminateAllocations` was on by default (seen after `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep EliminateAllocations`).

Results:

```
Benchmark                         Mode  Cnt           Score         Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testNewEliminate     thrpt   20    95912464.879 ± 3260948.335  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testNew              thrpt   20   103980230.952 ± 3772243.160  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testStaticEliminate  thrpt   20   206849985.523 ± 4920788.341  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testStatic           thrpt   20   219735906.550 ± 6162025.973  ops/s
MyBenchmark.noop                 thrpt   20  1126421653.717 ± 8938999.666  ops/s
```

Using a constant was almost two times faster.

Turning off `EliminateAllocations` slowed things down a tiny bit.

Comment: This is a very unfair benchmark, even though it uses JMH. 1) Writing a benchmark loop manually is a mistake; JMH does it for you. 2) Results are not consumed by the Blackhole. 3) Tests are not comparable: `testNew` consumes a lot of memory, because it saves ALL intermediate results together; this is not a usual case in real practice. 4) The way how tests are written makes impossible for JVM to apply allocation elimination optimization, but this optimization is crucial when dealing with short-lived objects returned from a method (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765687/).

Answer (score 2):

> Is the VM not able to roll all empty String arrays into one?

It can't do that, because distinct empty arrays need to compare unequal with `==`. Only the programmer can make this optimization.

> Contrast this practice with returning an empty String: we're usually perfectly happy writing `return "";`.

With strings, there is no requirement that distinct string literals produce distinct strings. In every case I know of, two instances of `""` will produce the same string object, but maybe there's some weird case with classloaders where that won't happen.

Comment: Cases between String and array are not equivalent as inlined "" is a String constant (compared to `new String("")`), whereas there is no equivalent "array constant" concept. String constants are further required by JLS to be intern()ed to be canonical.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb and say that the performance benefit, even though using constant is much faster, is not actually relevant; because the software will likely spend a lot more time in doing other things besides returning empty arrays. If the total run-time is even hours a few extra seconds spent in creating an array does not mean much. By the same logic, memory consumption is not relevant either.

The only reason I can think of for doing this is readability.